# JAXB not converting request class to required xml format

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a springboot module where I am using @XmlRootElement(name='request') to rename the xml request it creates for an api rest call, but the code is generating the request with the class name instead of applying xml properties which causes unmarshalling error at the recieving end. Dependency used is jaxb-api version 2.3.1 with java 1.8.

Other modules are working fine and they are generating the correct requests with the same code, just wanted to know what could cause JAXB annotations to not work properly. Can it conflict with any other dependency? as there is one javax.xml.rpc-api in this module

Comment: I am not quite sure but may be XmlType in favor of XmlRootElement is the right choice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Spring Boot application using JAXB for XML serialization/deserialization, the @XmlRootElement(name = "request") annotation should work as expected to rename the root element of the generated XML. However, if it's not working as expected, there could be a few reasons to investigate...

First of all, you mentioned that there's a dependency on javax.xml.rpc-api. This could potentially cause conflicts or interfere with JAXB annotations. JAXB and javax.xml.rpc are two different Java technologies for handling XML. Ensure that the conflicting dependency doesn't override JAXB annotations or configurations.

Next I would ensure the JAXB Context Configuration: Make sure that your Spring Boot application has been correctly configured to use JAXB for XML processing. Spring Boot typically configures JAXB automatically, but if you have any custom configurations or if you've disabled auto-configuration, ensure that the JAXB context is properly set up.

For example, you can configure the JAXB context explicitly by creating a Jaxb2Marshaller bean in your Spring configuration and specifying the package where your JAXB-annotated classes are located, just like this:

```
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.example.package"); // Replace with your package name
        return marshaller;
}
```

2 more less possible reasons, could be:

1. Check the Classpath (correct version of JAXB (jaxb-api and jaxb-impl) is on your classpath. )
2. Inspect Generated XML (verify that the generated XML indeed contains the  element by examining the output or using a
   tool to pretty-print the XML. This will help confirm whether the
   issue is with JAXB annotations or with the receiving end's
   expectations.)